# Display all Guild Names of a Bot in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

How can i make that when the Bot starts a file is created and all guild names and guild ids are listed in this file. And when a file is always there then the Bot should Update this file with the new Guilds and Guild ids.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far. What research have you done?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please read the [tour], [ask], and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](/meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/8289918).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guilds.json

```json
{
    Placeholder: null
}
```

The above is the file with the guild IDs

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    let guilds = client.guilds.cache
    const json = {}
    guilds.forEach(g => {
        json[g.name] = g.id
    });
    fs.writeFileSync('./guilds.json', JSON.stringify(json))
});

client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    const file = fs.readFileSync('./guilds.json', 'utf8');
    const json = JSON.parse(file);
    json[guild.name] = guild.id;
    fs.writeFileSync('./guilds.json', JSON.stringify(json));
})

client.on('guildDelete', guild => {
    const file = fs.readFileSync('./guilds.json', 'utf8');
    const json = JSON.parse(file);
    delete json[guild.name];
    fs.writeFileSync('./guilds.json', JSON.stringify(json));
})

client.on('guildUpdate', (oldGuild, newGuild) => {
    if(oldGuild.name === newGuild.name) return;
    const file = fs.readFileSync('./guilds.json', 'utf8');
    const json = JSON.parse(file);
    delete json[oldGuild.name];
    json[newGuild.name] = newGuild.id;
    fs.writeFileSync('./guilds.json', JSON.stringify(json));
});
```

My `fs` syntax may be wrong, but at least you should get the idea. On ready, you put all the guilds into the file, on guild create, you add that guild to the file, on guild delete, you delete the guild from the file.

Comment: Please fix my indentation, it’s really hard for me on mobile

Comment: thanks thats cool and work but what is with the Guilds the Bot is already in?

Comment: That is to 'refresh' it on bot restart

Comment: yes but i will that all guilds that my bot is in are displayed in this file but this method only make that when my bot joins a new guild the guild are listed in this file but when i restart the bot the file will be empty

Comment: If you are on v13 you may need Guild intents. I’m not really familiar with it.

Comment: @MrMythical Is there is any way that i can also add the invite link in the JSON file?

Comment: Use `<Guild>.invites.cache.first()`

Comment: @MrMythical One problem when i restart the bot JSON file cleared why?

Comment: The `.map` was the problem. I updated the answer and it should now work

Comment: @MrMythical Worked. If you give me a sample code that I get the guild invite URL also, It will help me more